# Simply throw exception with message in swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift

I am simply looking something up in the plist. If there was some sort of error. How do you just say Exception("Missing Information")

```
class func Lookup() throws -> String{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let url = defaults.objectForKey("url"){

        return url as! String
    }
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Info", ofType: "plist"), dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let url = dictionary["url"] {
            defaults.setValue(api, forKey: "url")
            defaults.synchronize()
            return url as! String
        }
    }
    return Exception("missing data") //something like this
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
enum LookupError: ErrorType {
    case MissingData
    case UnknownError
    etc..
}

class func lookup() throws -> String{
    ...blahblah
    guard url != nil else {
        throw LookupError.MissingData
    }    
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
do {
    try func()
} catch LookupError.MissingData {
    // do something
} catch LookupError.UnknownError {
    // do something else
}
```